# get checked radio buttons from variable assigned to selector

Tags: jquery

I know I can get checked radio buttons from a selector like this using `:checked`:

```
$('input[name="choices"]:checked')
```

But, if I already have a selector, can I then get the checked radio buttons without using `each` or a loop block?

```
var choices = $('input[name="choices"]')
var checkedChoices = ???
```

Since this only applies to radio buttons, it is safe to assume that only one will be selected at a time.

Comment: Use .filter() to get only checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use JQuery's .filter() method:

```
var checkedChoices = $(choices).filter(":checked");
```